# Javascript validation for textbox inside gridview c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am applying validation for textbox which is inside gridview.I have written following code but it is showing `NullReferenceException`. I think there is problem in FindControl.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Estimate/Js/DeliveryEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertValidation() {
        var TbWorkDetails = document.getElementById('<%=((TextBox)GridDeliverablesSheets.FooterRow.FindControl("TbWorkDetail")).ClientID%>');
    }
</script>
```

How to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 0):

just check whether the TbWorkDetails  is null or not if not null then write your code else just simply return false

Comment: As exception is occured before assigning value to TbWorkDetails.I can not check TbWorkDetails is null or not.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Find-and-validate-TextBox-and-DropDownList-controls-in-GridView-row-using-JavaScript-in-ASPNet.aspx   please check this link here is another example is given for the same